# Average of difference between 2 datetime fields then cast to time

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working in Google BigQuery.

I have a DeliveryDate and ShipDate field (both datetime). I am calculating the difference then averaging. My problem is that my data visualization software is having trouble picking up the date time format of, for example, '0-0-0 25:0:0'. I want to CAST or really any function to get just the time portion.

```
SELECT 
    CarrierName,
    AVG((DeliveryDate - ShipDate)) AS AverageShipToDeliver
FROM 
    `jan2022floyd.floyd_jan22.leaf_Q4_Jan22`
GROUP BY 
    CarrierName
```

Unfortunately I cannot add a CAST function into the above because 'AverageShipToDeliver' is not recognized and I can't do calculations inside of it.

Comment: Is it not sufficient to calculate `AverageShipToDeliver` as an integer that represents number of seconds or number of minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the date_diff function instead, it will return an integer that you should be able to work with more effectively.  You'll likely need to calculate at the delivery label though then average up.

```
select CarrierName
    , AVG(date_diff(DeliveryDate, ShipDate, DAY))
FROM `jan2022floyd.floyd_jan22.leaf_Q4_Jan22`
GROUP BY CarrierName
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff